# Pandas DF column values get changed but to_csv shows old values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to convert some excel files into csv. The follow code worked fine for .xlsx type files but is not working for .xlsm type files:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if(row[0] == 'X'): row[0] = 'Y'

csv_file = df.to_csv(name, index=None, header=True)
```

The df columns get changed but the output to the csv file remains as 'X'

Comment: Do you get an error message with the `.xlsm` type files?
Beyond that the pandas dataframe idiom lends itself to more efficient ways of accessing and changing data than iterating over rows.



`x_replace_mask = df.iloc[:,0]=='X'`, then do
`df[x_replace_mask]='Y` . 
Or, simply, `df.iloc[:,0].replace({'X':'Y'})`

Comment: There were no errors; the CSV files were created without the specific change.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised your solution worked at all; I believe `iterrows` returns copies of the rows, so modifying those copies shouldn't do anything. A better solution would be to use `.replace`:

```
df.iloc[:, 0] = df.iloc[:, 0].replace('X', 'Y')
```

Or, if you know the name of the column you want to replace `X` with `Y` in, use it:

```
df['column name'] = df['column name'].replace('X', 'Y')
```

Comment: This worked out quite well. I did not realize iterrows returned copies. Thank you